# Swift define and call inline closure directly

Tags: swift, closures

I can assign an inline closure to a function type

```
 > var a = { ()-> Bool in return true }
```

and use it:

```
 > true==a()
 $R2: Bool = true
```

if the function is a throw-away, it would be nice to use an inline directly. This doesn't work:

```
> true=={ ()-> Bool in return true } 
 error: repl.swift:16:5: error: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool' and '() -> Bool'
```

According to the error, the RHS is the inline's function type, not its return type. Is there a different syntax I should use? Is it possible to call an inline directly?

Edit, after answer: This comes in very handy in cascaded conditions in if statements: if b==2, { /* do something only if b==2 passes*/}(), let x = ... { ...} else {...}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> true == a()
```

compares `true` with the result of *calling* the closure `a` (with an empty argument list). You can do the same inline, but you must still call the closure:

```
> true == { ()-> Bool in return true }()
$R0: Bool = true
```

Note that a test for equality with `true` is always redundant, so this expression is identical to

```
{ ()-> Bool in return true }()
```

Comment: @P2000: What I meant is that you can remove the `== true` comparison. In your example: `if b==2, { /* do something only if b==2 passes*/}(), let x = ...`

Comment: Good catch, I fixed it. It was a typo. I updated the question to include this point. Thank you for your help, Martin.